# How to get the one year data with an interval of one hour based on the Datetime column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

```
SELECT 
      datetime,[ColumnT],[ColumnV],[ColumnVV]
FROM [Server].[dbo].[Table] 
where  ColumnT like 'XXXX'  and
       DateTime between '2017-03-01 09:00:00' and '2018-03-01 09:00:00'   
group by HOUR(DateTime)
```

I have tried to fetch the data using the above. Please advise to get the data.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to do some aggregation like SUM for each hour?

Comment: aggregation ...

Comment: I mean to say, do you want to show the sum/avg of records for each hour? It will be better if you add some sample data with expected output

Comment: You need to group by year, month, day and at last also hour to get the desired result

Comment: 00:00 1
01:00 2
02:00 3
03:00 4
04:00 5
05:00 6
06:00 7
07:00 8
08:00 9
I need the data at the time for example (for eg 12:00:00 - value)

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Tag appropriately!